# How to iterate over each position of a character of a string, for a list of strings?

Tags: python

So I have a list of strings, all of the same length, like this:

```
list_strings=["a-a--","-ab-b","a---a","b-b-a","aab-a"]
```

What I want to do it iterate over each position of the strings inside the list, so to calculate the number of times the character "-" appears in each position. In this case for example, position 0 has 1 "-"s, position 1 has 3 "-"s, position 2 has 1 "-"s, position 3 has 5 "-"s. But I want to do this for a file that has more than 100,000 strings

So far I have:

```
for i in range(0,len(list_strings)):
    for j in range(0,len(list_strings[i])):
        if list_strings[i][j]=="-":
            #count how many "-"s appear in this position and maybe save it in a list?
```

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: I blv. its reasonable to need O(N) for N characters, which is what you've got.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Does your solution work? If not how is it deficient? Why aren't you using `str.count`? ... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_strings=["a-a--","-ab-b","a---a","b-b-a","aab-a"]

# if every string in `list_strings` is same length:
out = [v.count('-') for v in zip(*list_strings)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 3, 1, 5, 1]
```

---

If some strings are different length:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
out = [v.count('-') for v in zip_longest(*list_strings)]
```

Comment: thank you for showing me both approaches, is there a way to also check for the count of the underscore"_"? as in, for each position count very "-" or "_"?  with count I can only pass one argument. I'm sorry I know this wasn't included in the question, just in case there's an easy answer

Comment: @tadeufontes If I understand you right, you can do `out = [v.count('-')+v.count('_') for v in zip(*list_strings)]`

Answer (score 1):

you are good.
just add `counter=0` variable who will add himself every time your `if` clause is true, and you will have the number of `'-'` in your list.

```
counter =0
for i in range(0,len(list_strings)):
    for j in range(0,len(list_strings[i])):
        if list_strings[i][j]=="-":
           counter = counter +1
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't do much explaining, so this is the code to start:

```
list_strings=["a-a--","-ab-b","a---a","b-b-a","aab-a"]

for string in list_strings:
    occurrence = 0
    check_letter = '-'
    for letter in string:
         if letter == check_letter:
             occurrence += 1
    print('string: ' + string)
    print('occurrences: ' + occurrence)
    print('\n')
```